# web site layout changes when re-size browser?

Tags: html, css

In my web site left padding remain fixed when re-size the browser. how can i make only left and right padding space of web site to reduce not the center content ?

Comment: You really need to add some code from your site so we can understand your question.

Comment: Do you have a link to your website?

Comment: i'm new to web sites how can i show it to you, I have one css and html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width of center content fixed in pixels or em,
And set left and right widths in precentage.